# al correr el codigo e intentar poner dos valores seguidos separados por un espacio en el primer input sale el error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

los valores que debo poner en el inicio separados por un espacio son
3  5 luego
405 313 778 (estos si aparte) y luego 1 131 82 - 3 129 81 - 1 21 45 - 2 125 81 - 2 157 95 (los 3 numeros separados por un espacio, pero cada 3 datos aparte).  el resultado deberia ser
2 297 -
3 777 -
1 1.98% -
2 5.11% -
3 0.13%

. también en el input que se llama info deben ir 3 valores diferentes separados solo por espacios, sin embargo, sigue tirandome "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

````
def main():

    n = 0
    while n < 1:
        inicial= input().split()
        n,m= int(inicial[0]), int(inicial[1])
    
    am,rm=[],[]

    for i in range(n):
        med= 0
        while med < 1:
            med= int(input())
        am.append(med)
        rm.append(0)
    
    for i in range(m):
        info= input().split(" ")
        s,ps,pv= int(info[0]), int(info[1]), int(info[2])

    if ps < 75 and pv < 55:
       rm[s - 1] += 7
    elif ps in range(125,135) and pv in range (80,85):
        rm[s - 1] += 1
    elif ps in range(135,155) and pv in range(85,95):
        rm[s - 1] += 7
    elif ps in range(155,175) and pv in range(95,105):
       rm[s - 1] += 15
    elif ps >= 175 and pv >= 105:
        rm[s - 1] += 30
    elif ps >= 135 and pv < 85:
       rm[s - 1] += 15
        

    dif= [e1 - e2 for e1, e2 in zip(am,rm)]
    
    print(min(rm))
    print(max(rm))
    for i in range(n):
        print(f" {rm.index + 1} {dif / am * 100: .2f}%")```
````

Comment: ¿Podrias adjuntar el texto completo del error? Copié y pegué tu código y no puedo reproducir lo que dices, de hecho, el código se ejecuta. Algo me dice que no estás indentando bien. Dado que no supiste poner el código correctamente en tu pregunta no sé si es exactamente así como lo tienes o un error al preguntar. Considera [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/539743/edit). Para colocar código se usa ``` codigo ```

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ya lo edité! perdon por las molestias no sabia como arreglarlo

Comment: Buen día, copié y pegué tu código y el error que comentas no es reproducible pero tienes un error en el `print()` del final, ¿Qué intentas hacer con eso?